# How to pass elements to other page layout sections from inside a nested route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a page layout with 3 separate sections: The sidebar, the header and the main body. I would like to fill the main body from the child route, while parent routes define the header or sidebar - but after trying to work with Providers and Context approaches, I couldn't quite find the right approach.

Here's a baseline / pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve:

Example Layout:

layout.tsx

```
export function DefaultLayout() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <!-- sidebar content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div className="page">
      <div className="page-header">
        <!-- header content goes here -->
      </div>
      <div className="page-body">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example routes:

router

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Route element={<DefaultLayout />}>
  <Route
    path="/dashboard"
    sidebar={<DefaultSidebar />}
    header={<DashboardHeader />}
  >
    <Route path="home" element={<DashboardHomePage />}>
    <Route path="stats" element={<DashboardStatsPage />}>
    <Route path="help" element={<DashboardHelpPage />}>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/user" sidebar={<UserSidebar />} header={<UserHeader />}>
    <Route path="overview" element={<UserOverviewPage />}>
    <Route path="accounts" element={<UserAccountsPage />}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

As seen in the simplified example above, I would like to define the overall Layout in a parent route, while "filling" the layout sections in nested routes. `sidebar={}` and `header={}` are just pseudo-code for the example, I realize that it's probably part of another `element={}` wrapper.

I've tried solving this by creating a `<SidebarProvider>` and `<HeaderProvider>` component, working with things like `useOutletContext` and passing the state downwards, but that didn't seem to work and was quickly getting hopelessly complicated (infinite loops, etc).

So, starting fresh: what would be a method to achieve the above behavior? If it's via providers, how should I structure them?

**Edit:** To clarify confusions: I want to decouple the Layout, the sidebar, the header and the routes (which hold the body). I think this should be possible with Providers, as I found examples of using Providers for a similar situation, just to set a page title which don't seem to work when I try to extend them with multiple elements. What would a Provider example, that takes a sidebar and a header, look like?

Essentially: I want to pass 2 elements from a child route, to a parent route. How do I do that?

Comment: Edited "class" to "className"; sorry, the `<div>s` were custom components at first, I changed them to HTML to keep the example more straightforward and forgot to use `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `header` and `sidebar` as props to the `DefaultLayout` route component and render them accordingly. Don't forget that in React we use a `className` prop instead of `class`.

```
const DefaultLayout = ({ header, sidebar }) => (
  <div className="layout">
    <div className="sidebar">{sidebar}</div>
    <div className="page">
      <div className="page-header">{header}</div>
      <div className="page-body">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Note that I added a `"layout"` class to the overall surrounding element of the entire element in order to set the overall page layout using a grid layout and assigned areas.

Example CSS:

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar page";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.page {
  grid-area: page;
}
```

You will then adjust the routes to pass the sidebar and header components to the layout route each.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    element={
      <DefaultLayout
        sidebar={<DefaultSidebar />}
        header={<DashboardHeader />}
      />
    }
  >
    <Route path="/dashboard">
      <Route path="home" element={<DashboardHomePage />} />
      <Route path="stats" element={<DashboardStatsPage />} />
      <Route path="help" element={<DashboardHelpPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route
    element={
      <DefaultLayout sidebar={<UserSidebar />} header={<UserHeader />} />
    }
  >
    <Route path="/user">
      <Route path="overview" element={<UserOverviewPage />} />
      <Route path="accounts" element={<UserAccountsPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-elements-to-other-page-layout-sections-from-inside-a-nested-route]

[image]
[image]

### Slightly more ***DRY*** solution

You can refactor the `DefaultLayout` to split the outer-most `div` from the inner sidebar and page `div` elements.

```
const DefaultLayout = () => (
  <div className="layout">
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

```
const SidebarHeaderLayout = ({ header, sidebar }) => (
  <>
    <div className="sidebar">{sidebar}</div>
    <div className="page">
      <div className="page-header">{header}</div>
      <div className="page-body">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<DefaultLayout />}>
    <Route
      path="/dashboard"
      element={
        <SidebarHeaderLayout
          sidebar={<DefaultSidebar />}
          header={<DashboardHeader />}
        />
      }
    >
      <Route path="home" element={<DashboardHomePage />} />
      <Route path="stats" element={<DashboardStatsPage />} />
      <Route path="help" element={<DashboardHelpPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path="/user"
      element={
        <SidebarHeaderLayout
          sidebar={<UserSidebar />}
          header={<UserHeader />}
        />
      }
    >
      <Route path="overview" element={<UserOverviewPage />} />
      <Route path="accounts" element={<UserAccountsPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-elements-to-other-page-layout-sections-from-inside-a-nested-route (forked)]

Comment: This was my first approach, but its hard to keep things DRY here - as 80% of the routes share the same Layout and could all be nested inside a parent `<Route>`. I really wanted to break things up in a way where the routes don't even need to know what Layout they're in, they just define what the content is and leave the layout choice to the parent. My example is simplified of course, but for this project, there are more than 300 routes broken up in different files. Is there no way to bubble two elements upwards? But yes, this is a fairly straightforward approach.

Comment: @Katai This approach is already pretty ***DRY***. Sure, you can refactor the `DefaultLayout` component to render only the outer-most UI and an `Outlet`, and create a `SideBarHeaderLayout` component that consumes the specific sidebar and header components. This would be *slightly* more ***DRY*** than the solution I proposed since all it *really* does is move the sidebar/header props down a nested level. I tried to keep the code as close to the same as your example, but if you want I can update my answer to provide a concrete example of the refactor.

Comment: @Drew_Reese what you describe (moving the sidebar/header props down a nested level) would be exactly what I'm looking for - so I would love to see an example of it, if you can provide one. I can't quite get it to work myself. Otherwise, you're right that your solution works well. Maybe add the nested version to your answer, in addition to the original suggestion (so that people can see both methods). Thank you!

Comment: @Katai I've updated my answer with the suggested improvement. Please do check it out when you have time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to render dynamically only one part of the app. In that case you can directly embed the routes inside your "dynamic" section.
In you case your Layout component would become:

```
export function DefaultLayout() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <!-- sidebar content goes here -->
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="page-header">
                <!-- header content goes here -->
            </div>
            <div class="page-body">
                <Routes>
                    //..your routes here
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

I made also a demo of what It'd look like:

[image: Edit naughty-lalande-j3378g]

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lalande-j3378g?file=/src/App.js:318-322.

Comment: This works, but my goal really was to keep all the elements separate and not have the routes inside the Layout. The Layout shouldn't know what routes it deals with, and the routes shouldn't care what Layout they're in or what structure it has - that's why I'm trying to set these elements from inside nested elements.

Comment: As far as I know this is a best practice. Either way setting up the routes this way gets as simple code as a simple "if (homepage) { render this } else if (settings)  { render this}". Is there any particular reason you want to keep them separate?

Comment: my goal is to decouple the layout from the routes, not combine them. A layout should be interchangeable without me having to modify the layout itself - I just change the Layout. This works fine with `<Route element={<SomeLayout />}>` and `<Outlet />`. My problem is, that I essentially need 3 separate `<Outlet />`s: sidebar, header and body. I realize that it's possible with Providers, somehow - I just can't figure out how.

Comment: What do you mean by interchangeable? And what would make this approach not interchangeable